# Install Atom for Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, variables, path, atom-editor

I just encountered the problem that Atom could not find the Python path. A lot of posts are about setting the paths, etc., which will sometimes not work for everybody. Can anybody help here?

Comment: While sharing your solutions to problems you've encountered is great, you should do it the proper way. Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer site. That means you should ask a *good question*, thoroughly describing the problem you're having. And then, you should answer  your own question, providing detailed information about how to solve the problem. As it stands, this is neither.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer, and do note that a question is *"solved"* when an answer is accepted, don't put it in the title.

Comment: Thanks guys for your annotations. I am new here and did not know how to post a solution :-) Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

If this does not work uninstall Python and Atom. While reinstalling Python make sure you click on "Add Python to Path" so you will not have any problems with setting the paths at all!

[image: Problem solved]